# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline Fingerprinting

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, fingerprinting

Simple question:

I've got a Rails 3.1 app running in staging, which is `RAILS_ENV=production`.  My problem is this:  `stylesheet_link_tag` produces a different fingerprint for my css files than the fingerprint that was produced by `rake assets:precompile`.

So when I request a page, the link to the stylesheet is looking for a file like:

```
/assets/front-1e3a4454e0d5434eccac1a053ca4c7fd.css
```

but in reality the file sitting in public/assets is

```
front-60b624d69d97b3ac5f288c54245a5ed5.css
```

and the browser returns a 404 Not Found.

Here is my linlk `stylesheet_link_tag :front`.  Can anybody explain to me why this happens?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Any solutions?

Comment: @thedelchop were you able to figure out why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same exact issue.  Best I can tell, this occurs when the precompile task runs during a capistrano deploy. I've had to remove the precompile from deployment and run the

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production   from the release directory after the app has been deployed. It's a pain if you're pushing code frequently.

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't able to, no, and the workaround is so old at this point I don't even remember.  Sorry.